# Mongoid query with OR and WHERE

Tags: nosql, mongoid

I am building a rails3 web app. Is there a query like this in mongoid

```
 db.collection.where((:status => "abc" OR :status2=>"abc") , :license=>"Active")
```

I don't know what fields are present in my collection, one between status and status2 field could exists in my collection or both may exists.

Update
I found that I could use any_of for OR but it is not working. The query is runny find but there is no result.

```
 db.collection.any_of(:status=>"abc",:status2=>"abc").where(:license=>"Active")
```

Comment: Did you try reading the docs?

Comment: ya. I found that i could use any_of but it is not working. my query db.collection.any_of(:status=>"abc",:status2=>"abc").where(:license=>"Active")

Comment: your query is wrong. Read the docs again.

Comment: thank you, found the answer its - db.collection.any_of({:status=>"abc"},{:status2=>"abc"}).where(:license=>"Active"). May be I posted this question a bit early.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posted this question without enough search. The answer is

```
 db.collection.any_of({:status=>"abc"},{:status2=>"abc"}).where(:license=>"Active‌​")
```